# How to insert values in a table taking value from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have table named shipments with columns `origin_state` and `destination_state`. I want a new column named `st_st` with the value `origin_state` _ `destination_state`.
For example, if a row has SC as origin and GA as a destination. I should get SC_GA in the `st_st`

I tried

```
INSERT INTO shipments(ST_ST) 
SELECT CONCAT(`Origin_state` , '_' ,`Destination State`) AS ST_ST 
From shipments;
```

this query starts to insert the values at the end of the table not to the corresponding row.
Please help.

Comment: please show your table schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
alter table shipments add column st_st varchar(255) generated always as
    concat(`Origin_state` , '_' ,`Destination State`) ;
```

You can also change the values using `update`:

```
update shipments
    set st_st = concat(`Origin_state` , '_' ,`Destination State`);
```

However, a generated column ensures that the value in `st_st` is always consistent, even for new rows and if the values change in existing rows.